# Testing in Nativescript Telerik Appbuider

Tags: telerik, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

I've searched all over and have not found anyone who has been able to test a Nativescript project built on the Telerik Appbuilder. Even if it means exporting the project externally and testing in command line, is there any way to test it with Karma and Jasmine/Mocha?

This is probably a stretch, but I'm guessing there's also no way to integrate with continuous integration, such as Jenkins?

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/testing  and nice article about CI https://therankamateur.co.uk/continuous-integration-and-nativescript-68c78cb89ff#.rtr6psq79

Comment: Thanks - that works for CLI. I'm talking specifically a project built on their Telerik AppBuilder Platform.

Comment: Telerik replied and said it's not possible right now, but are aiming for end of 2016.